# How to handle varying Panel Heights which cause gaps in a row?

Tags: html, css, asp.net-mvc, twitter-bootstrap, razor

**Question Background:**

I have a simple page in my MVC app that renders a list of `Panels`.

**The Issue:**

The Panels include information about products I'm displaying including the products title and image. I have set the image to be a max size of 105px. If the title of the product is long it was break to a second line, inturn this means that it pushes the next line Of Panels down leaving gaps in the rows. Please see the following diagram for an explanation:

[image]

**How do I set the markup so that the Panels are always the same height no matter the size of the image or title? I want to loose the gaps in the rows.**

**The MarkUp:**

This is the following MarkUp I'm using. please note the `foreach` loop that creates the list of Panels:

```
@{
ViewBag.Title = "Index";
Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";
}

@model List<ShopComparisonEngine.Models.ViewResponseRoot>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>
        Comparison Engine
    </title>
</head>
<body>
<div class="container">

    @foreach (var displayItem in (List<ShopComparisonEngine.Models.ViewResponseRoot>)Model)
    {
        foreach (var item in displayItem.DisplayItems)
        {

            <div class="col-sm-4">
                <div class="panel panel-default">
                    <div class="panel-heading">
                        <h3 class="panel-title text-center"><b>@item.Title</b></h3>
                    </div>
                    <div class="panel-body">
                        <a href="@item.url"><img src="@item.Image" class="picHeight img-rounded img-responsive center-block" /></a>
                        <h4 class="text-center">£@item.Price</h4>
                        <h4 class="text-center"><a href="@item.url" class="btn btn-success">See More</a></h4>
                        <h4 class="text-center">@item.Origin</h4>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        }
    }
</div>
```

Comment: Are you using Razor?

Comment: @eugensunic Yes I am.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19695784/how-can-i-make-bootstrap-columns-all-the-same-height?rq=1 , this can help you. read the answers and try to apply the CSS rules suggested there.